# Indexed columns slow pagination on large dataset

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have a table that has an index on three columns, say A, B, C columns in ascending order.

We need to retrieve the data paginated.

It is a large table > 150 million rows.

The query we are using is this:

```
select * from large_table order by A, B, C fetch first 100 rows only;
```

This is taking almost 2 min to run and the reason for that is that the order by is taking too long.

My question here is why Oracle is trying to order the columns if they are already ordered in the index?
Why doesn't it reads the index first and get the 100 rows without attempting to order by the full dataset?
Is there a way to read the rows based on the index?

NOTE: I also tried to replace the index for BTree index with no improvement.

Comment: What do you mean by " I also tried to replace the index for BTree index"? what is the type of index on these columns? and are you sure they are in the same order?

Comment: `null`s are not indexed, so if you do not have `not null` constraint on those columns, the index will not be used even in case of `select a,b,c from ...` unless there's (possibly artificial) `where` condition on that columns. It uses an index on not null column in the fiddle (18c, 21c): https://dbfiddle.uk/dnLIc4o5.

Comment: Also please verify if there is a relevant statistics on the table: Oracle may consider to use full table scan instead of index if it thinks the table is small. However, it looks like `fetch fisrt` forces cardinality estimate to be the number of rows requested, because it is not affected by manually set statistics (`dbms_stats.set_table_stats(..., numrows=>1)`) or `cardinality(tabname N)` hint, as you may see in the fiddle.

Comment: @Roger, pagination like this never performs well. Even when an index matching the ORDER BY columns is used with NOSORT (which you have to verify by looking at an execution plan), once you are being the first page of 100 rows every subsequent page will require scanning the index from left to right and counting until it finds the starting point. That will get slower and slower with each page.

Comment: If you need the data paginated in a specific order, you're better off creating a secondary table (with CTAS) and adding a sequence column that is generated with ROW_NUMBER according to your ORDER BY needs. Index that column. Then you can use BETWEEN [start] AND [end] on that column for your pagination, and it will seek to the starting point efficiently on each page.

Comment: @astentx, nullable values are not indexed if they are the only column(s) in a b-tree index. If you have a concatenated index of several columns and there is even one not-null column value, the index keys for that row will be stored in the index, including the null values. Whether Oracle will use the index or not for such a query as OP has is another matter.

Comment: Just tested it, and yes, as long as *one* of the indexed columns are defined as NOT NULL, Oracle can use the index for OP's query. Of course it might not choose to and it might require a hint, but it can use it even if the other columns are NULLable.

Comment: The columns were nullable and as per the comment form @astentx null values are not indexed, that seems to be the reason why oracle was doing a full scan in the table as per it could not be sure in advance if null values were present, therefore it could not use the index for the ordering.

Comment: where is your EXPLAIN PLAN?

Comment: @PaulW Of course you are right: for compound index a row will be indexed if any indexed column is not null, which is very well documented. For the index to be used it may be stated explicitly with `not null` constraint or implicitly with `where indexed_col_with_no_nulls is not null` which is logicaly constant true, but allows an optimizer to consider index. The intent was to point that Oracle should know if the row is indexed at least *to be able* to consider index scan. Without a table definition and a query plan it was a blind guess.

Comment: @PaulW you can post your explanation about nullable columns and I will mark it as right answer as per that was the isue in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for Oracle to consider using an index when your query does not apply any predicate to the index columns, at least one of the index columns must be defined as `NOT NULL`. If all the indexed columns are `NULL`able, then without a query predicate on any of them rows with all `NULL`s in the indexed columns would be candidate rows you would want to retrieve, but such a row cannot be found via the index, since Oracle does not store such all-`NULL` key values in b-tree indexes. Therefore Oracle cannot safely use the index to find the rows you are asking for.

Having said that, even with a viable index Oracle may not choose to use it, preferring a full table scan, particularly if you are asking for some non-indexed columns in your `SELECT` clause. If this happens and it's not fixed by stats gathering, you can force index use with a hint:

```
SELECT /*+ INDEX(large_table indexname_on_largetable) */ . . .
```

To get the sorting benefit of the index, the `ORDER BY` must match the index column list exactly, in the right order, and in the same direction as the index scan (e.g. `ORDER BY ASC` would require `INDEX_ASC` (the defaults), but `ORDER BY DESC` would require `INDEX_DESC`)